# Filling public_activity parameters with model instance attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to fill the `parameters` attribute of my activity model (from the public_activity gem), but without success.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model

  tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user },
          parameters: ->(controller, model){
            {foo: 'bar'}
          }
end
```

The first problem is that the parameters hash is always empty when I update a project. The second problem is, that `->(controller, model)` receives the controller and the model class, but not the instance. My aim is to pu two fields from the changeset on update into the parameters (an id and a string).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, although not through the model. It seems like, in more complex cases, you don't create it this way. You either create it in the model through a callback (which can be complicated then because of the missing `current_user`, unless you do some hackery), or in the controller.

The way I did it:

**Model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Common

  attr_accessor :previous_status_id

  before_save :remember_previous_status_id


  private

  def remember_prefious_status_id
    self.previous_status_id = self.changes['status_id'].first if self.changes.include? 'status_id'
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
# [...]
if @project.update_attributes project_params
  @project.create_activity :update, 
    owner: current_user,
    previous_status_id: @project.previous_status_id, 
    parameters: {
      # ...
    }

  # ...
```

**Migration**

```
create_table :activities do |t|
  # ...
  t.belongs_to :previous_status
  # ...
```

**Initializer**

```
PublicActivity::Activity.class_eval do
  belongs_to :previous_status, class_name: 'Status'
end
```

Answer (score 8):

A bit late answer but still might be helpful to others, who a trying to use default parameters hash in PublicActivity. As per the official docs:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      include PublicActivity::Model
      tracked :params => {
          :title => :title,
          :author_name => "Michael",
          :category_name => proc {|controller, model_instance| model_instance.category.name},
          :summary => proc {|controller, model_instance| truncate(model.text, :length => 30)}
      }
    end
```

You can refer to:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/public_activity/PublicActivity/Tracked/ClassMethods
for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `activity_params` variable on your model instance and then it gets saved to the activity as well. In your case like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
end

project = Project.new
project.activity_params = {foo: 'bar'}
```

For more info please see: http://rubydoc.info/gems/public_activity/PublicActivity/Common#activity_params-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user 
  }, parameters: :previous_changes
end
```

The following solution worked for me. You can have a look at the following link for more changes regarding changes in the active record api for version 5 https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/rails/upgrades/active-record-5-1-api-changes.html